# Python append to csv file without whiteline

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm writing a game in python. And after each round of the game (yes, the game has multiple rounds) I want to write the data to a CSV file.

this is my code:

```
with open('data.csv', 'a') as fp:
            for player in self.players:
                a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',');
                data = [[player.name, player.penalty(), player.score()]];
                a.writerows(data);
```

the output for this code (after two rounds) in the CSV file is:

> player1,10,10.0
>
> player2,5,5.0
>
> player1,20,15.0
>
> player2,10,7.5

The problem is that every time the script appends data to the csv file, there is a white line between the data. And the only time I want to append a white line is between the rounds. So the output should look like this:

> player1,10,10.0
>   player2,5,5.0
>
> player1,20,15.0
>   player2,10,7.5

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

My new working code:

```
with open('take5.csv', 'ab') as fp:
            for player in self.players:
                a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',');
                data = [[player.name, player.penalty(), player.score()]];
                a.writerows(data);
            white_row = ['\n'];
            a.writerows(white_row);
```

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: I'm guessing that this code is in a function and your are calling that function for every round with different values?

Comment: Yes that's right, but I have it working now, I wil update my script

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Python 3:**

```
with open('data.csv', 'a', newline='') as fp:
    for player in self.players:
        a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',');
        data = [[player.name, player.penalty(), player.score()]];
        a.writerows(data);
```

With python 3 there is change in the CSV module you can read [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

**Python 2.x:**

Just change the `open()` to binary `open('data.csv', 'ab')`

You can set control quoting using:

`csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)`

As from docs your options are:

> csv.QUOTE_ALL Instructs writer objects to quote all fields.
>
> csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL Instructs writer objects to only quote those fields
>   which contain special characters such as delimiter, quotechar or any
>   of the characters in lineterminator.
>
> csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC Instructs writer objects to quote all non-numeric
>   fields.
>
> Instructs the reader to convert all non-quoted fields to type float.
>
> csv.QUOTE_NONE Instructs writer objects to never quote fields. When
>   the current delimiter occurs in output data it is preceded by the
>   current escapechar character. If escapechar is not set, the writer
>   will raise Error if any characters that require escaping are
>   encountered.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this, but my version is 2.7 and "newline" is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Answer from above doesn't work. You should use a line terminator instead:

```
for player in self.players:
                a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n');
```

This works for both python2 and 3.

Also, the quoting options should be used in conjunction with a quote char. If no quotechar is used, quoting is obsolete.