# TypeError: string indices must be integers when trying to extract data from an API using Python

Tags: python, json

I am very new to programming and I am having a problem with the following:

I have a very simple and perhaps pointless task whereby I am trying to take longitude and latitude data from a JSON API and write to a CSV file. I have based the code on another that seems to work OK.

I keep getting the following error code:

> c.writerow([item['latitude']])_TypeError: string indices must be
>   integers

Can anyone help me??

**JSON code from http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json**

```
{
  "iss_position": {
    "latitude": 17.03894678089794, 
    "longitude": 1.17550020887323
  }, 
  "message": "success", 
  "timestamp": 1463137065
}
```

My Python Code

```
import requests
import csv

r = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json").json()

c = csv.writer(open("ISS.csv", "w"),lineterminator='\n')

for item in r['iss_position']:

    c.writerow([item['latitude'],['longitude']])
```

Error Message

```
C:\Python35\python.exe C:/Users/Ian/PycharmProjects/ISS/ISS.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ian/PycharmProjects/ISS/ISS.py", line 10, in <module>
    c.writerow([item['latitude']])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The value assigned to `iss_position` key (`r['iss_position']`) is a dictionary. So, iterating over it will yield keys (strings) rather than values (coordinates). It seems that this will do in this case:

```
c.writerow([r['iss_position']['latitude'],r['iss_position']['longitude']])
```

The `for` loop is not needed anymore. There are two keys in the dictionary under `'iss_position'` key, so the loop turned twice. It's enough to call the code above once.

Comment: Thanks Piotr, that has now written the coordinates to my .csv file, although it seems to write the data twice. Would you be able to advise how I can get new data to append to my .csv file instead of writing over it.

Comment: See my edit about the `for` loop. As for other unrelated issues, please Google them. There are plenty of resources here, including [appending to CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432610/python-append-to-csv-file-without-whiteline).